# Deploying two Grails apps on Tomcat ignores one DataSource

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, datasource

I have two applications each pointing to a different database. when I deploy these applications to Tomcat at the same time, whichever datasource gets loaded first is the same datasource that gets used for both apps. I am using the latest Tomcat and Grails.

Comment: is each of the apps deployed as a complete war or do you use library sharing?

Comment: I use library sharing. grails war --nojars, and all the libs are in tomcat_home/lib

any ideaS?

Comment: avoid library sharing. Some libraries use singletons. In case of library sharing, multiple apps use the same instance - that's what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

Configure datasources in Tomcat
h..p://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html

Access them via JNDI
h..p://www.grails.org/JNDI+Data+Sources

Comment: Isn't there something better? I mean, why it is this way by default? What use does it have to share DataSources.groovy and how does it even do that since the wars are supposed to be isolated? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't know exactly why Groovy behaves in such weird way (I have never deployed 2 applications to the same appserver), but using JNDI has always been reliable measure to treat application's datasource problems

Comment: Using JNDI didn't solve the problem! Actually we have to start 3 tomcat instances. I'm searching for a solution. Anyone?